# How can I type in the terminal after the process of "yarn start"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a Node chat app and I want to type in the terminal something but I can't type anymore after I enter the "yarn start"

[image: screenshot terminal]

I am following a tutorial and  he can type in his terminal after he enter the "yarn start" but in my case I can't

[image: screenshot YouTube tutorial]

Comment: On the second image you have a `+` icon top right where it says `bash`, you can create a new terminal window there. And on the right hand side you have the open terminals.

Comment: You need to open another terminal. Or press `ctrl + z` to move process to the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for answering me, I just figure it out how they do it, you just Ctrl C in the terminal to stop and you can now type.